# Trying to connect to a POP3 server mail

Tags: php

I'm actually working on an application that is supposed to connect on a POP3 mail server with the purpose of reading the mails every 5 minutes.

I've tried this to connect on my POP3 server :

```
 $mbox = imap_open ('my_mail_serveur:110/pop3}INBOX', 'user', 'password');
 echo "<br>";
 if($mbox){
    echo "ok";
 }else
    echo "not ok";
```

But I'm getting this :

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {my_mail_serveur:110/pop3}INBOX in /var/www/vhosts/sophinfo.com/subdomains/clients/httpdocs/inc/cron/monitoringEmail.php on line 128 Call Stack: 0.0008 703032 1. {main}() /var/www/vhosts/sophinfo.com/subdomains/clients/httpdocs/inc/cron/monitoringEmail.php:0 0.0036 813608 2. imap_open() /var/www/vhosts/sophinfo.com/subdomains/clients/httpdocs/inc/cron/monitoringEmail.php:128 
not ok
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What do you get with print_r(imap_errors());

Comment: I get this :
`Array ( [0] => Certificate failure for my_mail_serveur: self signed certificate: /C=US/ST=Virginia/L=Herndon/O=Parallels/OU=Parallels Panel/CN=Parallels Panel/emailAddress=info@parallels.com )`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `my_mail_serveur` with the IP of your actual server (88.190.216.226).

Comment: I've already tried this also, but I'm getting the same warning

Comment: Change `echo "not ok";` to `echo imap_last_error();` so you can read the error.

Comment: I get this error :
`Certificate failure for 88.190.216.226: self signed certificate: /C=US/ST=Virginia/L=Herndon/O=Parallels/OU=Parallels Panel/CN=Parallels Panel/emailAddress=info@parallels.com`

Comment: Ok, so I've been able to fix my problem by adding `/novalidate-cert` on my connections options

Thank you for your answers